# Is there a way to melt a data frame such that values columns are created separately on the basis of data type? (using python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which have hundreds of columns, to be represented into a desired format i applied melting, which is not satisfactory. The melt function creates a value column and append all the values of the column assigned to "value_vars" parameter irrespective of data type.
I am trying if i can get separate value columns based on the data type.

The data frame that i have:

time           place          Temperature       value1        Pressure       value2

2/4/2018          U.K          A                   3            C                 2

3/4/2018          U.K          C                   4            D                 6

4/4/2018          U.K          B                   6            A                 1

5/4/2018          U.K          D                   8            A                 4

Expected Output:

time           place          parameter       source        value

2/4/18           U.K          Temperature            A               3

3/4/18           U.K          Temperature            C               4

4/4/18           U.K          Temperature            B               6

5/4/18           U.K          Temperature            D               8

2/4/18           U.K          Pressure              C               2

3/4/18           U.K          Pressure               D               6

4/4/18           U.K          Pressure               A               1

5/4/18           U.K          Pressure               A               4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get columns by types, reshape by `stack` and join by `concat`:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = df.set_index(['time','place'], append=True)
a = df1.select_dtypes(object).stack().rename('source').reset_index(level=3)
b = df1.select_dtypes(np.number).stack().rename('value').reset_index(level=3, drop=True)
df2 = (pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
         .reset_index(level=[1,2])
         .rename(columns={'level_3':'parameter'})
         .sort_values(['place','parameter'])
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         )

print (df2)
       time place    parameter source  value
0  2/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      C      2
1  3/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      D      6
2  4/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      A      1
3  5/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      A      4
4  2/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      A      3
5  3/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      C      4
6  4/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      B      6
7  5/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      D      8
```

Another solution for select pair and unpair column after first 2 cols:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

df1 = df.set_index(['time','place'], append=True)
a = df1.iloc[:, ::2].stack().rename('source').reset_index(level=3)
b = df1.iloc[:, 1::2].stack().rename('value').reset_index(level=3, drop=True)

df2 = (pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
         .reset_index(level=[1,2])
         .rename(columns={'level_3':'parameter'})
         .sort_values(['place','parameter'])
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         )

print (df2)
       time place    parameter source  value
0  2/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      C      2
1  3/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      D      6
2  4/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      A      1
3  5/4/2018   U.K     Pressure      A      4
4  2/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      A      3
5  3/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      C      4
6  4/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      B      6
7  5/4/2018   U.K  Temperature      D      8
```

Comment: thanks for responding, but why am i getting this error "Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!"

Comment: @ShashankSinghYadav - Try `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` before my solution

Comment: the second one works partially, entries of different data types are getting mixed on the lower part of the data and source and values are getting swapped in the middle. (on the other note: what will be the solution if we just ignore the existence of "Place" column.)

Comment: @ShashankSinghYadav - Not sure if understand what is problem, are data confidental?

Comment: @jezreal yeah, data is confidential . Can you please ignore the "place" column and then try a solution....that way, there will be no problem regarding multi-index...i guess.